# How can I overcome PyTorch Tensor plotting problem?

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I am a new PyTorch user and here is the code I am playing with.

```
epochs=20  # train for this number of epochs
losses=[] #to keep track on losses
for i in range(epochs):
    i+=1 #counter
    
    y_pred=model(cat_train,con_train) 
    loss=torch.sqrt(criterion(y_pred,y_train)) 
    losses.append(loss)  # append loss values
    
    if i%10==1: # print out our progress 
        print(f'epoch: {i} loss is {loss}')
    # back propagation
    optimizer.zero_grad() # find the zero gradient 
    loss.backward() #move backward 
    optimizer.step()
plt.plot(range(epochs),losses)
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.
```

I know the problem is related to the type of the losses with the following kind of rows:

```
tensor(3.6168, grad_fn=<SqrtBackward0>)
```

Can you suggest how I can grab the first column (numeric values of this tensor) and make it plottable e.i. an array not a Tensor.

Comment: Please edit your post so that it doesn't contain an [image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`torch.Tensor.item`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.item.html).

So, replace the statement

```
losses.append(loss)
```

with

```
losses.append(loss.item())
```